# How do I use ASP.NET to display video from bytes in SQL database?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, video

I am in ASP.NET 2.0. I have uploaded a QuickTime movie to the database. It now resides as a byte array in sql server 2005. I am trying to determine how to read the bytes back out, maybe convert them to a stream and display the movie in the browser or some sort of device. I know this is broad, but can anyone even give me pointers on where to get started or if I am going about this the right way?

Comment: Databases aren't very good at storing BLOB's, so I'd use the filesystem for that, and just store the path in the database.

Comment: @FlySwat: SQL Server has a FILESTREAM type that is designed for storing BLOB's.

Comment: Interesting paper on when and when not to store blobs in the DB: http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525

Comment: From your link: objects smaller than 256K are best stored in a database while objects larger than 1M are best stored in the filesystem.

Videos will be larger than 1M.

Comment: @Flswat: that's correct.

Comment: @Flyswat: also note: that paper was written before the introduction of the SQL Server FILESTREAM type

Answer (score 0):

Mitch has shown how to get the bytes. The next thing for you to figure out is how you would display a video - *any* video in a normal HTML page. ASP.NET will eventually render a normal HTML page, so you'll have to figure this part out eventually.

Once you've got that figured, all you have to do is take Mitch's bytes, and connect them with your "play video" thing, and you'll be all set.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make an ASP.NET page which reads the content as already discussed and set the appropriate MIME type using ContentType = "video/quicktime" when your page streams it out.

If you need [a page which contains the video in a window](http://www.stager.org/imovie/qtweb.html), you would make a separate (static or aspx) page that wraps the viewing component in HTML with a reference to your streaming page to provide the video.  The page I linked to also shows how you can launch in QuickTime.

Answer (score 0):

this is an ugly solution.  I have been asked to do this in a project and it's a nightmare.  You can't really 'stream' a compressed movie like that out of a database.  If you write the binary contents to a generated http response, a) if the movie is big you don't get a response until the whole payload comes (i.e. no buffering) b) in my case I'm getting an error because the embedded player wants to stream.  The solution is to generate a temporary file on a media server and provide this connection to the embedded player.